# Extract string inside of a big string delimited by two different phrases in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've searched in the web for a way to do this, so far I've only encountered examples that don't really meet the criteria I'm looking for...

I want to extract the string that appears between "received from:" and "The information transmitted"

Usually the string will appear as:

> 2014-01-23 13:26:13 - Jim Superman received from:
>   JIM.superman@superheroes.com
>
> please bla bla bla, we need a new super hero in the complex
>
> supermanager of managers test bla bla [wawa]
>
> The information transmitted

Comment: How about you try to adapt the examples you encountered to what you're trying to do?

Comment: How about `.split(start).pop().split(end)[0]`

Comment: @elclanrs post as answer?

Comment: What happens if someone sends this question in such a message? @elclanrs solution would split the message in the middle.

Comment: @64BitBob: You're right there. I'll just delete is not even worth it given that there are already other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple substring:

```
 var str = ...; // Where ever it came from

 str = str.substring(
         str.indexOf("received from:") + "received from:".length, 
         str.lastIndexOf("The information transmitted"));

 console.log(str); // Check the results
```

Note how the length is added to "received from:". This is so the text "received from:" won't be included in your output.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, this is what I was looking for. I'm not that familiar with JavaScript and this worked wonders.

Comment: what if the same text repeats more than one time? Is there a way to stop it from being added to the str variable?

Comment: That's a slightly different question. If you've got many messages that need to be parsed out, you will first need to understand how to split them before using the parsing answer I gave. You would need to post an example so the common divider can be found. (Possibly as a different question.)

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex?

```
str = "2014-01-23 13:26:13 - Jim Superman received from: JIM.superman@superheroes.com..."  
/(?: received from: (.*?) The information transmitted)/.exec(str)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
var text = "...";
var fromText = "received from:";
var endText = "The information transmitted";
var extractedText = text.substring(text.indexOf(fromText) + fromText.length,
                    text.indexOf(endText));
```

and you can also do this:

```
var extractedText = /\breceived from:(.*?)\bThe information transmitted\b/.exec(text)[1];
```